# C++ Include Confusion

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have the following issue with my C++ application (I'm just starting out with C++).

I'm fairly sure that it relates to includes in some way, but I believe I am correctly using include guards, so not sure what else I can do.

Example:

If I declare the following header file with the function body in the header file, the application compiles and runs as expected. *If I split out into separate .h and .cpp files however, the build fails with the error copied at the end of this post.* I'd like to correctly separate the implementation from the header as I understand this is a) the correct way to do it and b) results in faster builds.

I have included screenshots for the Configuration Properties > Linker > Input and the General > Use of MFC as this have had to be changed during the project build to satisfy requirements (I need to use "Use MFC in a Static Library").

So, how can I split my files out properly and not have my build fail? Thanks.

**json_ops.h (all in header file)**

```
#ifndef JSON_OPS_H
#define JSON_OPS_H

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../srclib/rapidjson/document.h"

namespace cdm_data_distributable
{
    class json_ops
    {
    public:

        void test_json() const;
    };

    void json_ops::test_json() const
    {
        // json parsing example

        const char json[] = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";

        rapidjson::Document d;
        d.Parse<0>(json);
    }
}

#endif
```

**json_ops.h, json_ops.cpp (separate files)**

Header file

```
#ifndef JSON_OPS_H
#define JSON_OPS_H

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "../srclib/rapidjson/document.h"

namespace cdm_data_distributable
{
    class json_ops
    {
    public:

        void test_json() const;
    };
}

#endif
```

.CPP File

```
#include "json_ops.h"

namespace cdm_data_distributable
{
    void json_ops::test_json() const
    {
        // json parsing example

        const char json[] = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";

        rapidjson::Document d;
        d.Parse<0>(json);
    }
}
```

**Resulting Errors**

```
error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

"void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(new.obj)

"void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgdel.obj)    C:\SVN\CdmDataCds\Application\CdmDataDistributable.Ui\uafxcwd.lib(afxmem.obj)   CdmDataDistributable.Ui
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're going to put function definitions in a header, outside of the class definition, you must mark them `inline` to avoid multiple definitions.

Comment: You're mixing different compiler settings for the different source files. If I knew which settings to check I'd leave an answer, but check them all.

Comment: @MarkRansom - could you elaborate on how you know that I have an issue with the compiler settings?

Comment: It's complaining about duplicate symbols from `LIBCMTD.lib` which is the standard library. There are different versions of the standard library depending on your compiler settings, and the only way to get a conflict is by linking more than one of them. The compiled modules have an embedded flag to tell the linker which library to link.

Comment: P.S. If you figure out which settings caused the problem, leave it in an answer.

Comment: I have put together a version of the application with no 3rd party dependencies, and I now have the same issue, but no idea how I might be linking tomultiple LIBCMTD libs.

Comment: @grx I told you, the libraries are linked automatically *based on the settings for each source file*. You have two different sources with two different settings, thus linking two copies of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using pre-compiled headers; you need to include the stdafx.h in every cpp file. Simply add the `#include "stdafx.h"` line in your cpp, before `#include "json_ops.h"`.

If `json_ops.h` is included elsewhere, `stdafx.h` won't be included systematically to your `json_ops.cpp` file.

Comment: I don't use VC, but AFAIK "stdafx.h" should only be in the `.cpp` files. OP has it in the `.h` file currently.